# Eclipse BPMN 2.0 modeler plugin for Eclipse Che

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, bpmn

Does Eclipse BPMN 2.0 modeler plugin support Eclipse Che? or is there a way to convert it to support Eclipse Che?

Answer (score 0):

No. Eclipse Che doesn't have Eclipse BPMN 2.0 plugin and afaik there is no way to convert it.